Issue with grabbing data from object
I'm having some trouble getting the right values to show up in this following code. The console log is correct, but when the actual information is being plugged into the page, it's off by 1.
What I'm hoping to get displayed is:
Name    James   person ID   1
first location  $35
fee amount calculated
fee3    a million in spacecash
Name    Jordan  person ID   2
second location $40
fee amount calculated

Here's the code:


$(document).ready(function() {
  for (person of personInformation) {
    const personTable = document.createElement("table");
    personTable.innerHTML = "<thead><th id='personName'>Name</th><th id='personId'>person ID</th></thead>";
    personTable.setAttribute("id", "table");

    const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    newRow.setAttribute("class", "personRow");
    const first_name = document.createElement("th");
    const person_id = document.createElement("th");

    console.log('person', person)

    person_id.textContent = person.person_id;
    first_name.textContent = person.first_name;
    console.log(first_name);
    $("th#personName").after(first_name);
    $("th#personId").after(person_id);
    personTable.appendChild(newRow);
    for (fees of person.fees) {
      const feeRow = document.createElement("tr");
      const fee = document.createElement("td");
      const amount = document.createElement("td");
      fee.textContent = fees.name;
      amount.textContent = fees.amount;
      console.log("fee", fee);
      feeRow.appendChild(fee);
      feeRow.appendChild(amount);
      personTable.appendChild(feeRow);
    }
    console.log(person_id);
    console.log(first_name);
    const persons = document.getElementById('test');
    persons.appendChild(personTable);
  }
  console.log(personInformation);
  $('#personSearch').on('input', function() {
    let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    let searchVal1 = $('.personRow').find('td').text();
    let searchVal2 = $('.personRow').text();
    $('form').filter(function() {

      console.log('searchVal1', searchVal1);
      console.log('searchVal2', searchVal2);
      $(this).toggle($(this).text()
        .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > 0);
    });
  });
});
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="test">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  const personInformation = [{
      "person_id": 1,
      "first_name": "James",
      "fees": [{
          "name": "first location",
          "amount": "$35"
        },
        {
          "name": "fee",
          "amount": "amount calculated"
        },
        {
          "name": "fee3",
          "amount": "a million in spacecash"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "person_id": 2,
      "first_name": "Jordan",
      "fees": [{
          "name": "second location",
          "amount": "$40"
        },
        {
          "name": "fee",
          "amount": "amount calculated"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
</script>



Thanks for any suggestions!

IDs should be unique. You're using the same IDs in the headers of each table. Use class='personId instead of id='personId

Also, you should restrict your selectors to just the current table. $("th.personName") matches the personName class in all the table headers, not just the current table.

@Barmar I know I should've been using classes*, thanks for that catch. I am having trouble narrowing down this selector though. I thought that using the selector within my "for" would be sufficient.

No, jQuery doesn't know that you're in a for loop. It just searches the DOM for everything matching the selector. You can use $(personTable).find("th.personName") to search in the current table.

@Barmar That made a lot more sense! Thank you for the help
